# Right numbering text content

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Home/} }
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cool}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{Introduction}
 ... other chapters...
\end{document}
```

When I add

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
```

it happens that in the 'Contents' of the pdf document the page the indicate the position of the chapters are numbered wrong .I seems that the page containing the abstract are countered so the pages indicated in the content are shifted and their numbers result higher..

Comment: You should compile at least twice after any sectional unit change in order for the ToC to settle. So, after compiling again, is the page numbering correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to compile twice. At the second time it will number it correctly.

Comment: You should [accept this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) as well.